# Is it possible to pack a local variable with particular alignment?

Tags: c, memory-management

code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    char b[10];
    printf("%p\n", &b);
    int c;
    printf("%p\n", &c);
}
```

outputs:

```
0061fefc
0061fef2
0061feec
```

It is obvious that `b` occupies 12 bytes memory becuase the default memory alignment makes the start address of `c` is a multiple of 4. It is possible to disable the memory alignment? I know `#pragma pack` can pack a structure, can it pack a local variable to make `b` occupy only 10 bytes? This is an interview question that makes me interested. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `0061FEFC - 0061FEF2 = A` (not `C`). Did you mean `0061fef0` for the middle one?

Comment: @WeatherVane `b` is padded before, not after, since stack grows downwards. `0061fefc-0061feec-4` = `C` (assuming `sizeof(int)==4`)

Comment: @rustyx  `0061fef2` does not have a 4-byte alignment, and OP state it occupies 12 bytes, not 10.

Comment: @jl0x61 what exactly was the interview question? Any packing will depend on the compiler: the C standard only mentions packing in respect of bit-fields, and nothing about *how* or *where* variables are stored. So which compiler is in question?

Comment: @WeatherVane: The standard does say some things about how objects are stored. 6.2.8 discusses alignment requirements and provides `_Alignas` for requesting stricter alignment. Do not go overboard in thinking the C standard defines only an abstract model of computing. It is a very practical document.

Comment: Assuming `sizeof(int)` is 4 or more, it's actually the alignment of `c` that needs to be adjusted.  Look up `alignas` (C++11) and `_Alignas` (C11).  Before C11 or C++11 you would have to resort to compiler-specific techniques.   There are also gotchas with aligning variables differently from what the compiler does by default

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, I note that the alignment will be an implementation-defined value. It wasn't initially clear to me whether the OP asks a) why the alignment of the `char` array is not 4 or b) how it can be made other than 4 (with a typo in the stated output). I guess it was a) and that the compiler aligns byte-size values at 1 or 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard does not provide any facility to request relaxed alignment of objects, and there is little or no value in such a feature for independent objects (objects that are not members of a structure).

Structures are sometimes packed, using extensions to standard C, because the bytes in them need to be laid out consecutively for some specific use, such as transmitting them in a network message, or because padding in them may waste large amounts of space when a great many instances of the structure are held in memory. No such purpose occurs with a single independent object.

The `char` array shown does not occupy twelve bytes. It occupies ten bytes. The other two bytes are either unused or are used by the compiler for other purposes not evident in the addresses examined. In a structure, padding bytes are reserved—held unavailable for other use—to give the desired alignment. In this situation, bytes may have been skipped to give the desired alignment, but they are not reserved for that purpose. If a two-byte object were needed, the compiler could insert it into those bytes.

The amount of stack space wasted due to alignment requirements is generally small because, unlike with structure members, the compiler is free to rearrange objects to use space efficiently. And the stack pointer generally must still satisfy alignment requirements of the application binary interface (ABI), so some space for alignment may still be needed regardless of the alignment requirements of objects on the stack.

Comment: @rustyx: What is a “data cube”? I very much doubt your client has gigabytes of data on the stack.

Comment: @rustyx: As my answer states, structure members are sometimes packed. It is independent objects for which there is little or no use in doing so. I will update for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Variable packing is an implementation-defined feature. So there is no standard way to do it.

Also I don't think it is possible with GCC, clang or MSVC.

- `alignas` and `__attribute__ ((aligned))` can increase but not decrease alignment.
- `__attribute__ ((packed))` and `#pragma pack` don't seem to work outside structs, even though [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes) suggests otherwise:

> The `packed` attribute specifies that a variable or structure field should have the smallest possible alignment...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    __attribute__ ((packed)) char b[10];
    printf("%p\n", &b);
    __attribute__ ((packed)) int c;
    printf("%p\n", &c);
}
```

Output:

```
warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     __attribute__ ((packed)) char b[10];
                                       ^
warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
     __attribute__ ((packed)) int c;
                                  ^
```

Clang output a similar warning. MSVC silently ignores `#pragma pack` there.

All in all it's a poor interview question because it's too specific; there is little, if any, correlation between knowing this and being a good programmer. Though sometimes questions like this are used to probe one's tolerance for stress :)